# browser engine with OpenGL backend

Tags: opengl, browser

Is there a browser engine that may use OpenGL as backend or adpater library to provide such? So that a web page can be rendered using a usual programmable pipeline of OpenGL.

I thought most browsers would use well known 2D frameworks that maybe would be provided with adapters by 3rd party, but just cant figure out if for example Webkit could work from a single mainstream 2D library.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of WebKit will use the GPU accelerated graphics APIs provided by the OS if available. Direct2D on Windows and OpenVG on other systems if available. That being said it would be perfectly possible to implement a OpenGL backend to WebKit.

I suggest you look at current developments regarding Wayland on Linux, which will require some major changes in the way applications to their graphics business. There should be already substancial work on the WebKit-GTK+ bindings to make it use EGL created graphics surfaces. It is *trivial* to bind such EGL surfaces as OpenGL texture.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGLES is not a 2D library, but I presume you meant frameworks that use OpenGLES for primarily 2D texturing. Chromium is one of the good examples of how OpenGL ES2 can be used for this, it accelerates canvas, CSS, and composition among other things using OpenGLES2.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

Until recently, the cairo-directfb backend for Webkit used to be quite popular, but now with every SOC having GLES2 support, things have changed. See for example below:

http://luorhino2006.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/build-webkit-over-pango-cairo-and-directfb-from-scratch/